# How to highlight UITextField when selected?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

I am trying to get the UITextField to appear highlighted in blue similar to how Apple does it. However, when I attempted it, the blue highlight is offset a bit to the right. All textfield code and anchors were done programatically. How do I fix this? Is this an issue with the anchors? I have looked at other stuff on stack overflow, but nothing really discusses this problem. Below is my code for the UITextFieldDelegate.

```
extension LoginController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == emailTextField {
            textField.layer.borderWidth = 2
            textField.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            textField.clipsToBounds = true
            textField.anchor(top: emailTextField.topAnchor, leading: emailTextField.leadingAnchor, bottom: emailTextField.bottomAnchor, trailing: emailTextField.trailingAnchor)
        } else if textField == nameTextField {
            textField.layer.borderWidth = 2
            textField.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            textField.clipsToBounds = true
        } else if textField == passwordTextField {
            textField.layer.borderWidth = 2
            textField.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            textField.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            textField.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.layer.borderWidth = 0 // default width
    }
}
```

[image: Image of What is Happening]

Comment: How are you achieving the text offset?

Comment: This is a good point! I have an UIView which contains the Textfields. The textfields are then offset by a constant 12. I now understand why it looks the way it does. Would I have to (un)offset the layer by -12? How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

From the comments, I deduce that the `UITextField` is a subview of a container `UIView`. Of which you're offsetting the `UITextField` by 12 points. So in this case, you can set the border to that super view to get the result you want.

```
extension LoginController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if textField == emailTextField {
            textField.superview?.layer.borderWidth = 2
            textField.superview?.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            textField.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            textField.superview?.clipsToBounds = true
            textField.anchor(top: emailTextField.topAnchor, leading: emailTextField.leadingAnchor, bottom: emailTextField.bottomAnchor, trailing: emailTextField.trailingAnchor)
        } else if textField == nameTextField {
            textField.superview?.layer.borderWidth = 2
            textField.superview?.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            textField.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            textField.superview?.clipsToBounds = true
        } else if textField == passwordTextField {
            textField.superview?.layer.borderWidth = 2
            textField.superview?.layer.borderColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0, green: 0.4784313725, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
            textField.superview?.layer.cornerRadius = 5
            textField.superview?.clipsToBounds = true
        }
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        textField.superview?.layer.borderWidth = 0 // default width
    }
}
```

Comment: It's getting closer! But now the highlighting occurs around the entire UIView Container, when I only want it to highlight the specific section that the user is clicking on.